# mitmproxy for only one specific domain

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I have this python script (`test.py`):

```
from mitmproxy import http

OGG = open('testfile.ogg', 'rb').read()
SIZE = str(len(OGG))

def request(flow):
    flow.response = http.HTTPResponse.make(
        200,
        OGG,
        {'Content-Type'  : 'application/octet-stream',
'Content-Length': SIZE})
```

I want to send the HTTP Answer to a Client if a specific Domain gets requested but I couln't figure out how to. At my end all HTTP request will be answered with the OGG file.

I tried the following:

- I used this command: `mitmproxy -T -p 8080 -s test.py -i "test.example.com"`
- Because only the IP addresses showed up in mitmproxy I tried to use the IP instead: `mitmproxy -T -p 8080 -s test.py -i "93.184.216.34"`

May someone have an answer?

Comment: try `dir(flow.request)` and see what you can find? Might be `flow.requst.url`? Or something like that? This is just a guess.